# MATLAB execute function for multiple variables in loop

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

To process data in MATLAB I have to execute a certain function, let's call it `function()`. Since there is much data to be processed, like large array `Time` or `Voltage` (but many more) I execute those one by one like this:

```
TimeNew = function(Time);
VoltageNew = function(Voltage);
... etc
```

So this is done around 10 times. Moreover, I have to do such a thing multiple times, resulting in around 30 lines of code which all do the same thing but to a different variable.

Is there a way to optimize this? I am using the most recent version of MATLAB (2015b) and have all toolboxes installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be to store the input array into a `struct`, them use that struct as input of the function.

In the function you can identify the number and content of each field by using `fieldnames` and `getfiled` built-in function.

The function could return a `structure` as output whose names can be made the same as the ones of the input struct.

In the example below, three arrays are generated and the function siply compute their square.

```
var_1=1:10;
var_2=11:20;
var_3=21:30;

str_in=struct('var_1',var_1,'var_2',var_2,'var_3',var_3)

str_out=my_function(str_in)
```

**The function**

```
function [str_out]=my_function(str_in)
f_names=fieldnames(str_in)
n_fields=length(f_names);

for i=1:n_fields
   x=getfield(str_in,f_names{i})
   str_out.(f_names{i})=x.^2;
end
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: Thanks, but won't I get the only variable str_out then?

Comment: Oh, and I think I need to move the function declaration in another .m file, right? I get the error that 'Function definitions are not permitted in this context'.

Comment: Yes, the function should be in a separate file. Wrt the output: yes, the output variable will be a struct with the same fields of the input structure

Comment: OK, I understand the output will be a struct as well. But can I just access a generated variable from that?

Comment: What di you mean with _just access a generated variable from that_?

Comment: So if I get a struct back with the variables 'TimeNew' and 'VoltageNew', how would I access those variables?

Comment: I'm restricted by the single file unfortunately, so I cannot make a new .m file for the function. I'll accept your answer since it solved my question, because my external restriction that I'm limited to the single .m file has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I do not know the content of your unique `.m` but, perhaps, you can paste the body of the function directly in your file. To access to the output variable: since in the output struct they have the same names of the variable in the input struct ==> str_out.var_1 will be the output of applying the function to str_in.var_1 and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100853/discussion-between-il-raffa-and-bastiaan).

Answer (score 0):

You could try `cellfun`

```
allResultsAsACell = cellfun(@function, {Time,Voltage,...,varN});
```

This is equivalent to

```
allResultsAsACell{1} = function(Time);
allResultsAsACell{2} = function(Voltage);
...
allResultsAsACell{N} = function{VarN};
```

The issue is just matching up the indices with the values.  I'm sure you could code those in as well if you needed (e.g. `timeInd = 1; voltageInd =2; ...`)

To see more on the `cellfun` method, type

```
help cellfun
```

into your MATLAB terminal.